# How to require a user-installed gem in ruby when system-wide gem with higher version is also available?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have two versions of a gem installed: system-wide `1.3.2`,
and user-installed `1.0.0`.

I need to use only version `1.0.0`, which is installed in my home 
dir. Is there a way to tell `gem` to prefer user-installed gems?

Comment: try to specify the GEM_PATH variable, pointing to the gem v2, and specify PATH to gem folder at the beginning of all PATHs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify which gem version to use by using the `gem` command before you `require` it.

```
gem 'foo', '1.0.0'
require 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can specify the GEM_PATH variable, pointing to the [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) version 2, GEM_HOME to path to gems for the selected [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) interpreter, and specify PATH to binary folder at the beginning of all PATHs, which contains the [gem](/questions/tagged/gem) version.
2. Use [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm), or [rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv) apps to control [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)/[gem](/questions/tagged/gem) apps per project.